# Is it advisable to attend a conference in Germany with talks by German presenters in English if you don't speak German?

Tags: conference, germany

There is an upcoming conference in Germany, all the talks will be in English, however all the listed participants are also German. Only speaking English I'm wondering if it would be inadvisable to go, as everyone will speak German during non-talk times?

Is this true or am I being too paranoid?

Comment: related: [What to do when no one speaks English around you?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15363/what-to-do-when-no-one-speaks-english-around-you)

Comment: I suspect many attendees will speak neither German nor English as their first language, and that you will find English used by many as the "lingua franca" if the conference schedule is in English, as attendees will be a self-selected group with a reasonable grasp of the language, and will expect others to be so too. My experience of English-language conferences in Italy and Spain with speakers from many countries was that English was most common in the corridors.

Comment: When I was a student visiting various European departments, I always found it easier to hang out with other people *not* from the host country — for example, French students and postdocs in Germany, or German students and postdocs in France.

Comment: as Kate is pointing this out: listed participants = speakers?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here are some claims that I think you will agree are true:

- Anyone who attends a conference where all the talks are in English can understand spoken English reasonably well
- You don't live in Germany and are considering attending. You are probably not the only person considering it
- Anyone willing to give a technical presentation in English can probably both understand and produce spoken English reasonably well

I believe these add up to you being able to find people for "hallway conversations" in English pretty easily. You might have some lonely lunches if you find yourself at a table with people who all speak German and exclude you. I have this problem with people who all discuss (in English) something I don't understand at all and don't want to learn (eg how to install Exchange on a server.) I generally try to prevent this by striking up a conversation with a fellow attendee at the end of the session that is right before lunch, and suggesting we go to the lunch line together.

Comment: +1 for your first point. I think this sums it up entirely.

Comment: I would post an answer if I had anything to add to this (so +1). I can offer the anecdotal evidence that I am currently at a conference in Germany, and hallway conversation takes place in many languages, but most commonly English. Then again, in my case the set of attendees is international and most of them don't speak German.

Comment: Small hint from a German: Germans tend to fall back to their own language in spare time, not to exclude you, but because it is more efficient for them, and Germans just love efficiency, especially Scientists and Engineers. It is absolutely acceptable if you kindly remind them of the fact that you do not understand German. They will usually excuse for their switch of language and use English to include you.

Comment: I disagree with your third point. I have seen some **bad** presentations in "English".

Comment: I not only disagree with point 3, also in the question it's explicitly said that point 2 does not hold either.

Comment: @Zane listed participants are typically presenters. It's a rare conference that tells you everyone who is attending. The OP is considering attending. Surely some other nonGermans are too.

Comment: In my area (algebra) it's not at all uncommon for the conference website to list all attendees.

Comment: The points are mostly true, but I have seen enough evidence against (1) and (3). (Well, I've even *been* part of the evidence against (1)).

Comment: @TaraB: So, in your area, conferences have no last-minute registration that is possible on the morning when the conference begins, for people who spontaneously decide to attend?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I'm sure they do usually allow last-minute registration, but that's not particularly relevant to the original question, since people who register at the last minute are pretty likely to be locals anyway.

Comment: @TaraB: At least at my German university, there are plenty of foreign researchers who have been living here for several years and still do not speak any German.

Comment: @TwoThe - but how can it possibly be more efficient to speak German?  As any UI designer knows a German sentence is between 10-20% longer as a rule than the English equivalent (at least as written words).  That's not just more letters - it's also more syllables....therefore it must surely take more time to speak .... German scientists and engineers would surely appreciate those undeniable metrics when considering efficiency ...

Answer (score 10):

Don't worry, Germans are usually polite. Being polite is to include all people in a conversation. So if the common language of a group is English, they'll switch to English to accommodate you. Furthermore, Germans attending the conference will expect to have attendants not speaking German and that conversations in the hallways will be in English too.

Comment: "Germans attending the conference will expect to have attendants not speaking German" - this. If they truly expected everyone attending to speak German, the conference talks would be given in German, as well. In my estimation, Germans are often eager to speak English (for example, readily switching to English when a single person present does not speak German), but not so exaggeratedly that a whole conference would be held in English if 100% of the audience were known to understand German.

Comment: There are some herd effects, and in my limited experience (we) Germans tend to switch when talking with each other, even though non-German-speakers are near (maybe more readily than other folks, I don't know). It is always appropriate to ask nicely if they can switch to English, though, and some may even *expect* you to speak up! (Who knows whether you understand and are just shy? Isn't it rude to assume no German ability just because a person looks foreign? ...)

Comment: @Raphael: the assumption that English will work for "foreign-looking people" is not a given.  I cannot really distinguish French-speaking and English-speaking people with African origin by their looks.  So the first bet outside of particular contexts like a conference is German, with an offer to switch if that does not work.  At a conference, it is usually embarrassingly easy to pinpoint Germans from other Western Europeans.  It think it's almost harder to tell them from _Eastern_ Europeans.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that the conference attendees will be at a higher educational level,
which probably means they can not only listen to talks in English, but probably are also able to communicate in English.

So yes, I thank it's safe to go to the conference and you will be able to talk to people in English with no big problem.

I guess from  your reservations that you are aware that it is not always easy to get along with English in Germany. Don't expect sales agents or bus/taxi drivers to talk English. And even if people speak English, they might not be very fluent.

And I must admit that all other participants being German is strange - whatever reason there is that talks are in English, it is surprising that participants do not come from outside Germany. I'd propose to call the organizers just to make sure that talks are in English.

I don't think you're paranoid here. E.g. Universities will have lectures announced in English, but hold them in German (as long as nobody objects).

And if there are so many German speaking people, groups often will talk in German. Then you shouldn't be shy - just throw in a remark and make clear you only speak English. I'm pretty sure they will switch language then.

Note: I'm saying this as a German living in Germany, with some experience with conferences at different national levels, sometimes visiting conferences where most participants are locals not speaking German.  In the last case, it's really important to not be too shy - when you try to join a discussion, make clear you do not understand what they say as soon as you get the chance - maybe a simple "hello, how are you" is already enough to achieve awareness.

I guess you will get to know some nice colleagues.

Comment: I am a Brit living in Germany. In Germany it is usual for educated people to speak quite good English. Depending on your subject, most of the books will be in English anyway. 
Some people from the East of Germany (what used to be the "new" Bundesländer) may have learned Russian as a first foreign language instead, but if they can't speak English they probably won't turn up anyway?

Comment: @RedSonja: good to hear this - however, in Germany a lot of things are quite dependent on education level. Nice nick though.